# Allow Contacts (Individuals) to register themselves and login with a password, on a Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, contacts, registration, online-registration

I am looking for a way to let visitors of a Wordpress website register themselves with an e-mail address and a password, which should create a new contact (individual) in the CiviCRM back-end, so that they may login again later and edit their personal data and register for events.

This seems a pretty straight forward use-case to me, but i couldn't find anything about it online - maybe i am asking the question in the wrong way?

My best bet so far is to use the REST API and maybe to save me some time using a Caldera Form for registration, but then i still need to setup some "user account" functionality otherwise and i feel like i am missing a simple and obvious solution that has surely been used a million times already.

Sorry for being a noob and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and elegant solution:

In Wordpress, activate "anyone can register"

Use the "Ultimate Member" plugin to create a login page
*(register-shortcode: [ultimatemember form_id="22"])
(login-shortcode: [ultimatemember form_id="23"])*
(remove everything except email and password from the registration form - only the email address will be synced to civi-crm automatically and nothing more is required for login)

Insert the shortcode of a CiviCRM-Profile into the "Default Profile" form in edit mode
*(shortcode: [civicrm component="profile" mode="3" gid="1"])*

now, users can register to your wordpress page, which will create a new civi-contact containing only their e-mail address. then, in their profile page, they can enter the rest of their personal data. when logging back in, their personal data will be displayed again and editable.

About CiviCRM Profiles and Wordpress Integration:

- https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#viewedit-user-account-new-user-registration-with-profiles
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/#shortcodes-using-the-classic-editor-wordpress-versions-49x-and-prior

Comment: If you create a profile and set it to 'require CMS user create' (or whatever it is called) in the Advanced Setting of the Profile, wouldn't this take care of the requirements without needing another plugin?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Trouble is that option doesn't allow users to choose their password there and then, it has to be done via n email, and I've got experience on a few sites now of that just causing the most immense confusion

Comment: fair point. if an email was triggered then saying 'use this link to set your pw' would that help? if if was drupal then would just link to /user/password